# Using quantile in Flux (Julia) in loss function

Tags: machine-learning, julia, flux.jl

I am trying to use quantile in a loss function to train! (for some robustness, like least trimmed squares), but it mutates the array and Zygote throws an error `Mutating arrays is not supported`, coming from `sort!` . Below is a simple example (the content does not make sense of course):

```
using Flux, StatsBase
xdata = randn(2, 100)   
ydata = randn(100)

model = Chain(Dense(2,10), Dense(10, 1))


function trimmedLoss(x,y; trimFrac=0.f05)
        yhat = model(x)
        absRes = abs.(yhat .- y) |> vec
        trimVal = quantile(absRes, 1.f0-trimFrac) 
        s = sum(ifelse.(absRes .> trimVal,  0.f0 , absRes ))/(length(absRes)*(1.f0-trimFrac))
        #s = sum(absRes)/length(absRes)   # using this and commenting out the two above works (no surprise)    
end

println(trimmedLoss(xdata, ydata)) #works ok

Flux.train!(trimmedLoss, params(model), zip([xdata], [ydata]), ADAM())

println(trimmedLoss(xdata, ydata)) #changed loss?
```

*This is all in Flux 0.10 with Julia 1.2*

Thanks in advance for any hints or workaround!

Comment: isn't this like text book example of a nondifferentiable loss function?
If so, I have seen some hacky code that trains Flux NNs with gradient free optimizers, but I don't have any handy.

Comment: Perhaps you can decompose the problem into a differentiable loss and the projection onto a convex set, and then implement a projected gradient method? OTOH, I'm not sure whether that's sensible, given that the loss will not be convex anyway...

Comment: Yes, certainly strictly it is not differentiable. But, heuristically it works quite well with other optimizers (Levenberg-Marq etc.), in particular when the trimmed fraction is small. With a stochastic gradient descent it should even matter less IMHO. It worked in an earlier version of Flux, without Zygote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ideally, we'd define a [custom adjoint](https://fluxml.ai/Zygote.jl/dev/adjoints/) for `quantile` so that this works out of the box. (Feel free to open an [issue](https://github.com/FluxML/Zygote.jl/issues) to remind us to do this.)

In the mean time there's a quick workaround. It's actually the sorting that causes trouble here so if you do `quantile(xs, p, sorted=true)` it'll work. Obviously this requires `xs` to be sorted to get correct results, so you might need to use `quantile(sort(xs), ...)`.

Depending on your Zygote version you might also need an adjoint for `sort`. That one's pretty easy:

```
julia> using Zygote: @adjoint

julia> @adjoint function sort(x)
         p = sortperm(x)
         x[p], x̄ -> (x̄[invperm(p)],)
       end

julia> gradient(x -> quantile(sort(x), 0.5, sorted=true), [1, 2, 3, 3])
([0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0],)
```

We'll make that built-in in the next Zygote release, but for now if you add that to your script it'll get your code working.

Comment: You Sir, are my hero and saviour.